# retrieving procedure result using MySQLi and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I use the following code to retrieve data from sql in php

```
if ($q=$db->prepare("call p_test(?)")){
    $q->bind_param('s',$token);
    $q->execute();

    $q->bind_result($r1, $r2, $r3);

    if ($q->fetch()){
        echo $r1.
    }
}
```

above code works fine when it's not calling a procedure. but when I use to call a procedure, I face with a strange problem with the result set.
when the procedure returns only one column $r1 will be filled out. but when I have more than one columns in result, fetch is done but no result's given.
in both tests the number of result and bind_result columns are same.

I can't understand the reason for such behavior. am I going wrong with the way I try to get the expected result from a procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible your procedure is returning more than one result set. You might need to use something like `next_result` (at least that's what it is in mysqli).

Comment: thanks Chris! i was pushing into a variable using "select @var:=field from.." method that was treated as a row.